# codeigniter and ajax contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to use ajax within my contact form in a codeigniter app. I have it to where the ajax call is made, but no post data is being sent to the server. I can't figure out why. Please help.

I do have some returns in there, but they do nothing. Also, $this->input->post('name') is null.

Form view

```
<?php
                    echo form_open('welcome/submit_contact');

                    echo form_error('name');
                    echo form_label('Name', 'name'"');
                    echo form_input('name', set_value('name'), 'id="name);

                    echo form_error('email');
                    echo form_label('Email', 'email');
                    echo form_input('email', set_value('email'), 'id="email"');

                    echo form_error('phone');
                    echo form_label('Phone', 'phone');
                    echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone'), 'id="phone"');
                    #echo '<h5>Do not start with "1" and no dashes.</h5>';

                    echo form_error('message');
                    echo form_label('Message', 'message');
                    echo form_textarea('message', set_value('message'), 'id="message"');

                    $submitData = array(
                        'name'  => 'submit',
                        'value' => 'Submit',
                        'id'    => 'button'

                    );
                    echo form_submit($submitData);

                    echo form_close();
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function() {

                    $('form').click(function() {

                        // get the form values
                        var form_data = {
                            name: $('#name').val(),
                            email: $('#email').val(),
                            message: $('#message').val()
                        };

                        // send the form data to the controller
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/submit_contact'); ?>",
                            type: "post",
                            data: form_data,
                            success: function(msg) {
                                $('form').prepend('<h5 class="good">Message sent!</h5>');
                                $('h5.good').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
                                alert(msg);
                            }
                        });

                        // prevents from refreshing the page
                        return false;   
                    });
                });
                </script>
```

Controller function

```
function submit_contact()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<h4 class="bad">', '</h4>');

        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        echo "name = ".$name;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|alpha_dash|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone' , 'trim|integer|exact_length[10]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|max_length[1000]|xss_clean');

        // there are validation errors
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            return "error";
        }
        else // there are no validation errors
        {
            /*************************
            need to actually send the email 
            *************************/
            return null;
        }

    }
```

EDIT: I've updated the code in my question. Basically now if there are validation errors, how would I get them to display on the form? I'm assuming I would return a value from my controller and then have a statement in my ajax success that if msg == "error" display the errors elseif msg == null, display success message. But how would i tell my view to display those errors based on an ajax success variable?

Comment: what is the extra " doing in this line?    echo form_label('Name', 'name'"');

Comment: Your name is null because of this  echo form_input('name', set_value('name'), 'id="name);
your id="name is not closed with an "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should put id on input and textarea not on label i.e.

```
$data = array
(
   "name"=>'message',
   "value"=>'message',
   "id"=>'message'
)


form_textarea($data);
```

if you set the id on the label then jquery will pick up nothing from what the user inserted and also codeigniter validation won't work correctly. This is why your post result to be NULL

the same for other input field

**EDIT**

you are asking data via ajax so return a nice json object (remove all your debug prints first):

```
// there are validation errors
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    echo(json_encode("validate"=>FALSE));
}
else // there are no validation errors
{
    /*************************
    need to actually send the email, then send you mail 
    *************************/
    echo(json_encode("validate"=>TRUE));
}
```

then test it on your ajax success function to display positive or negative message

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            $('form').click(function() {

                // get the form values
                var form_data = {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    message: $('#message').val()
                };

                // send the form data to the controller
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/submit_contact'); ?>",
                    type: "post",
                    data: form_data,
                    dataType: "json"
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        if(msg.validate)
                        {
                           $('form').prepend('<h5 class="good">Message sent!</h5>');
                           $('h5.good').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
                        }
                        else
                           //display error
                    }
                });

                // prevents from refreshing the page
                return false;   
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Seems to have done the trick. I had to fix some mistakes in your answer, but basically I can't use the codeigniter form_error()'s if using ajax is what i gathered. I think I understand.

Comment: yes if you display errors with ajax then the codeigniter report will be lost, but you still have the validation which is not bad :)